# Remove escape "\" character in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xml

I'm trying to upload xml file with Alamofire 5 `multipartFormData`. For the data part it has to be `String` and when I made the xml file to String it contains escape characters. I tried `replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")` but it remove all the String inside my xml. If I tried `replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "")` it turns `, with: "")` to String. Is there a way to remove the backslash? Thanks.

** Please don't mark duplicate because I tried all of the answers but did not work on my case **

Here is the sample xml

```
<code displayName="Vital signs" codeSystemName="LOINC" code="8716-3" codeSystem="12345"></code>
<title>Vital Signs</title>
<text>Measurement period:null-null

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Measurement</th>
                <th>Date/Time</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Mean artillery pressure</td>
                <td>2019-10-15/12:11</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</text>
<entry typeCode="DRIV">
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tRmb.png)

After I tried `xml.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")`
[it remove "" in xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcgdO.png)

Comment: To help people to help you edit your question to include a sample (part of) your string, what you want this sample to be changed to, and code snippets showing what you tried and the results you got. Without such information people will be largely guessing, and you'll also get downvotes (3 as I type this).

Comment: Are you sure there are any backslashes in your string? The `\"` shown in your image (it is not clear how this image was made) is a way to enter a quote when writing a string literal, the backslash is not in the resultant string value itself. Some ways of showing a string value can show characters escaped as well, again those escapes are not in the string itself. Your attempt removed all the quotes as that is exactly what you specified - replace a quote (`"\""`) with nothing (`""`). To write a backslash in a string literal you just escape it: `"\\"`. HTH

Comment: @CRD I did po in debug console and copy & paste to an empty file. As you see in the image there is \" in there. I tried manually remove it in empty file and use postman upload to the server it works. But I can't do that in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment:

> @CRD I did po in debug console and copy & paste to an empty file. As you see in the image there is \" in there. I tried manually remove it in empty file and use postman upload to the server it works. But I can't do that in Xcode.

It looks you don't have any backslashes in your string. Simple code:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
   let withQuotes = "A \"quoted\" word"
   print("withQuotes |\(withQuotes)|")
}
```

Place breakpoint on the final brace and run:

```
withQuotes |A "quoted" word|
(lldb) po withQuotes
"A \"quoted\" word"
```

"po" is showing the value of the string as a literal - quoted and with escape, but the string *value* doesn't include those quotes or escapes.

For the record to remove backslashes in a string value you can use:

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

called on a string literal or variable.

HTH

Comment: Yes. After few tries it is not there. I found out the problem for Alamofire wasn't from the escape was something else. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove `"\"` character from string in `swift5`

Example :

let yourString = "StackOver\flow"

```
 let newStr = yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\"#, with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

print(newStr) // StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**